# How to get two outcomes after a Do statement has been terminated?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need two outcomes after a Do Else While statement, right now the user can input data and it will be stored in a String, if they want to add anything else they type 'y', if 'n' it will end the program and tell them what they've inputed. If they input neither of those and input 'd' for example it stops the statement running and takes me through to the Else statement

**In the Else statement I want two outcomes**, either "You have added the following" and "Error, you inputted something wrong"

**Here is the Do Else While statement:**

```
do {
        System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
        System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
        if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter : ");
            list.add(input.next());
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have added the following:");
            System.out.println("Error, you inputted something wrong");
            break;

        }
    } while (true);
```

What do I write to get two outcomes depending on what the user has done? (said 'n' or wrote something wrong).

Comment: Just put another `if` (or better `else if`).

Comment: What would you consider "wrong"? A number instead of a string?

Comment: The first call to `input.next()` reads a word and the second call reads a second word so you would read `y 1 y 2 y 3 y 4 y 5` but you wouldn't be able to say `n` as this would be an error. :P

Comment: BTW `YES` or `Yes` is also an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
    System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
    if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
        System.out.println("Enter : ");
        list.add(input.next());
    } else if (input.next().startsWith("n")) {
        System.out.println("You have added the following:");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error, you inputted something wrong");
    }
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another `if-else:`

```
do {
  System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
  System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
  if (input.next().startsWith("y")) 
  {
    System.out.println("Enter : ");
    list.add(input.next());
  }
  else 
  {
    if(//valid input condition)
      System.out.println("You have added the following:");
      else  
      System.out.println("Error, you inputted something wrong");
    break;
  }
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce another condition in the else. Preferably, use else if:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
    System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
    String userInput = input.next();
    if (userInput.startsWith("y")) {
        System.out.println("Enter : ");
        list.add(input.next());
    } elseif (userInput.startsWith("n")) {
        // user wants to stop 
        System.out.println("You have added the following:");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error, you inputted something wrong");
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! The only problem I have now is that it takes two inputs before it registers. This is the output: 

Add more? (y/n)

n


n


You have added the following:

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "IF" statement inside else statement

```
    if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
        System.out.println("Enter : ");
        list.add(input.next());
    } else {
        if (input.next().startsWith("n")) {
            // Your code for "n" 
        }else{
           //else here.
           System.out.println("You have added the following:");
           System.out.println("Error, you inputted something wrong");
           break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the logic and flow of your program is slightly off. I would change it to this.

Code:

```
    boolean keepGoing = true; // can use a boolean to change the while loop condition to false.

    while (keepGoing) {

        System.out.println("Enter : ");
        list.add(input.next());            

        System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
        System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");

        if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {  // 'if' to check if 'y', then execute this code.          

             keepGoing = true; // don't really need this, but it's here as example

        } else if (input.next().startsWith("n")){ // 'else if' to check if 'n'.

            System.out.println("You have added the following: " + list);            
            keepGoing = false; //change to false to stop the loop

        } else { // and lastly a single 'else' if the input was invalid based on 2 previous conditions.

        System.out.println("Error, you inputted something wrong"); // if for some reason the input isn't accepted this will show. 

        }

    }
```

It follows a more logical flow and easier to understand. A simple while loop is easier for others to understand being that they can evaluate the condition before they enter the body of the loop.

You also don't need the Boolean and can simply use `true` in the while loop and `break;` in the `else if` portion, but as with do while loops, breaks can create confusion as far as when others need to look at your code once you start writing larger programs.